# Getting the length of a vector without using the length() function

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to get the length of a vector without using the length() function.

Anyone who can help me with that?

Comment: You can do `max(seq_along(v1))` or `tail(seq_along(v1), 1)`

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Agree with Colin. What do you want to do? Length is a best property to take it.

Comment: nrow(as.data.frame(vector))

Comment: If the goal is complexity, this returns the length of any numeric vector: `sort(a)[which(a==max(a))[length(which(a==max(a)))]] - sort(a)[which(a==min(a))[1]] + max(seq_along(a)) - tail(seq_along(a), 1) +1`. Using length() seems easier.

Comment: @FlorianMaas, you are also using `length` in your code

Comment: Ok that was pretty stupid, haha.

Comment: @FlorianMaas You can replace `length(which(a == max(a)))` with `sum(a == max(a))` ;)

Comment: `sum(a*0+1)` also returns the length.

Comment: @ColinFAY can you show me how to get the length using for loop? if it is possible. im also not allowed to use the length function

Comment: If this is an assignment for a class, you'd probably be better experimenting by yourself than asking here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, here are several ways :

```
max(seq_along(v1)) 
tail(seq_along(v1), 1)
nrow(as.data.frame(vector))
```

Though I really don't know why you want to do that. Length is a Primitive — so calls C code —, and you will hardly find a faster solution (if this is what you're looking for).

```
> length
function (x)  .Primitive("length")
```

Best

Colin

Comment: Thanks, I was/am not allowed to use the length function due the task.

Comment: also `NROW(v1)`

Comment: @Colin FAY can you show me how to get the length using for loop? if it is possible. im also not allowed to use the length function

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum function to find length of vector without using length() function.

```
data <-c(2, 7, 5, 3, 2, 9, 6, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 6, 5)
data.freq.table <-count(data)
n <- sum(data.freq.table$freq)
```